# What are good / simple techniques available for segmenting non-cursive handwriting images?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, image-segmentation

I need to process English hand-written form fields. So the hand-writings are expected to be mostly non-cursive but the letters may occasionally overlap with each other slightly, with some punctuation symbols (period, comma, dash, slash,) and the image scanned may contain the form field box lines. For the individual characters, a convolutional neural net trained with NIST dataset would be good fit. Though I need to first break out the letters correctly.

I could write a "traditional" algorithm to just guess the boundary by checking the amount of contiguous space from top to bottom. But I want to see if there are better / known / intelligent techniques (neural network or otherwise) for segmenting these images.